# How can I send dynamic parameters to template in Azure Devops Yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

How can I add send several dynamic parameters to a template with azure devops yaml?

```
- pwsh: |
          $affected = npm run nx affected:apps -- --base=origin/master  --head=HEAD | grep -E '( - )(\w|-|\d|_)+'
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=affected;]$affected"
      - template: build.yml
          parameters:
            affected: $env:AFFECTED
```

I think `$affected` is a list of string, here is the log when `Write-Host "apps are ${affected}"` :

[image]

Looks like ``` affected: $env:AFFECTED``as parameters doesn't work. Here is the error : ```Mapping values are not allowed in this context`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mapping values are not allowed in this context

The cause of this issue could be the YAML structure.

You could try to change the `-template` structure.

For example:

```
      - template: build.yml
        parameters:
          affected: $env:AFFECTED
```

The `parameter` and `affected` field need to move forward two spaces(`parameters` and `template` are **aligned**).

Then this pipeline may work fine.

Here is a doc about [the template sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#job-stage-and-step-templates-with-parameters).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, indeed the format was incorrect, now it can access the build.yml file. However I still have an issue : Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value '$env:AFFECTED'
Looks like I cannot pass a variable as a template parameters